# Dynamically resize TabControl and Form width to the number of TabPages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol, autosize

I have a windows form with a TabControl and a ListView.
When I run the application, I want the `Width` of the TabControl to increase/decrease to show all the TabPages without horizontal scrollbar and have the Form resize it's `Width` accordingly, to insure that the TabControl and ListView are visible.

A screenshot is below.

[image]

Comment: As a user I would hate this idea (of automatically resizing forms) as it will interfere with the layout I chose for my desktop. And, of course, it will soon hit the screen size limits.

Comment: Can't you just use `.GetTabRect()` to measure the tab strip? Or discover the position of the last tab? (which is a thin wrapper around TCM_GETITEMRECT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-controls#tab-size-and-position) though perhaps you should just set the tab control to multi-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To auto-size a TabControl to the size of its Headers, you need to calculate the width of the text of each Header. It's simpler in case the [TabControl.SizeMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.sizemode) is set to [Fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabsizemode), since you can set the [ItemSize.Width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.itemsize) and all Headers will have the same width.

If the `TabControl.SizeMode` is set to the default `Normal`, you have to measure the Text of each Header, adding `1px` for the Border (`2px` if it's the second TabPage - small *bug* in the base Control).

In the first case, the size of the TabControl is:

```
tabControl1.Width = tabControl1.TabPages.Count * (tabControl1.ItemSize.Width + 1);
```

in the second case, measure the text of each Header using [TextRendrer.MeasureText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext):

```
private int MeasureTabPagesWidth(TabControl tc)
{
    if (tc.TabPages.Count == 0) return tc.Width;
    int newWidth = 0;
    int border = tc.TabPages.Count == 2 ? 2 : 1;
    var flags = TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding;

    using (var g = tc.CreateGraphics()) {
        foreach (TabPage tab in tc.TabPages) {
            newWidth += TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, tab.Text, tc.Font, 
                new Size(int.MaxValue, tc.Font.Height + 4), flags).Width + border;
        }
    }
    return newWidth;
}
```

**Setup the Layout**:

- Add a TableLayoutPanel to your Form, with one Row and two Columns (i.e., remove one Row)
- Add the TabControl to the Cell on the left and the ListBox to the other Cell.
- Set both Cells's style to `AutoSize` (**after** you have added your Controls).
- Set the TableLayoutPanel to: `AutoSize = true`, [`AutoSizeMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.panel.autosizemode) `= GrowAndShrink`
- Set the Form to auto-size in the same way
- Set the Form's [MinimumSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize) and [MaximumSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize). The former is usually set to the design size, the latter is up to you; you could use the current [Screen WorkingArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea) as reference.
- Calculate the new Width of the TabControl when the Form is created or loaded (i.e., in its Constructor or `OnLoad()` or `Form.Load`), so the Form will auto-size to the size of the TableLayoutPanel, whici in turn auto-sizes   to the size of its child Controls.

Now you can add or remove TabPages at run-time and the Form will auto-size to the width you calculate in the [TabControl.ControlAdded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controladded) and [TabControl.ControlRemoved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlremoved) event handlers (also checking whether the Control added is of Type `TabPage`).

**Example**:

- The **`MeasureTabPagesWidth()`** method is the one shown above.
- The TableLayoutPanel is named `tlp1`
- The TabControl is named `tabControl1`
- The Buttons used in the visual example have names that define their role.

```
public partial class AutoSizeForm : Form
{
    public AutoSizeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabControl1.Width = MeasureTabPagesWidth(tabControl1);
    }

    private void tabControl1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        // Event notified after the TabPage has been added
        if (e.Control is TabPage) {
            tabControl1.Width = MeasureTabPagesWidth(tabControl1);
        }
    }

    private void tabControl1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is TabPage) {
            // Use deferred execution, since the TabPage is removed after 
            // the event handler method completes.
            BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> tabControl1.Width = MeasureTabPagesWidth(tabControl1)));
        }
    }

    private void btnAddPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("New TabpPage Text"));
    }

    private void btnRemovePage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count > 0) {
            tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    private void btnAddCtlToTLP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tlp1.ColumnCount += 1;
        tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        var mc = new MonthCalendar();
        tlp1.SetColumn(mc, tlp1.ColumnCount - 1);
        tlp1.Controls.Add(mc);
    }
}
```

**This is how it works**:
<sub>Tested in Windows 7, since this appears to be the System in use</sub>

[image: Form TabControl AutoSize]

**Sample Project**:
[Sample Project on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/132E6BRu3_FrLVqcYgZZW68lKySTj-ELl/view?usp=sharing)  (`.Net Framework 4.8` - `C# 7.3`)
<sub>Rebuild the Solution before running</sub>

Comment: I copied your code ver batim into my project after looking at your project code and couldn't figure out why my form didn't resize right, Then I looked at the tab controls font and when I changed it to Segio UI 9pt, it worked for me.  I agree... if there are too many tabpages, the form will grow out of control. Will have to ask my project leader about this.

Comment: Also Jimi... Can I please ask you what program you use to do that screen capture animation showing how the tab control grows and shrinks? I hope it's FREE as I'd like to use that for future screen captures. Thanks

Comment: About the Form Size, you can set the `MaximumSize` property. The `MinimumSize` Property is usually set to the design Size. I've added a note about this. -- The Font is not the problem: verify further what was the difference. -- The animation program here is generated by [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) and, yes, it's free and open source (update it each time it asks for it).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Starting form for this example]

Starting out with that form, I'm going to add 8 tabs at run-time, calculate width of the text in the tabs + padding size x2 (both sides of the tabs) and then resize controls as needed.

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Clear our default tabs.
        tabControl1.TabPages.Clear();
        //Add more tabs than would be visible by default
        for (int i=1;i<=8;i++)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Tab " + i.ToString());
        }
        ResizeTabControl();
        ResizeListViewControl();
        ResizeForm();
    }
    void ResizeTabControl()
    {
        int tabCount = tabControl1.TabCount;

        float length = 0;
        using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
        {
            //Iterate through the tabs and get the length of the text.
            for (int i = 0; i <= tabCount - 1; i++)
                length += g.MeasureString(tabControl1.TabPages[i].Text, tabControl1.Font).Width;
        }
        //Resize the tab control where X is the length of all text in the tabs plus padding x 2 x total tabs.
        tabControl1.Size = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(length) + (tabCount * 2 * tabControl1.Padding.X), tabControl1.Width);          
    }
    void ResizeListViewControl()
    {
        //Move listview 10 pixels away from tabcontrol's edge
        listView1.Location = new Point(tabControl1.Location.X + tabControl1.Width + 10, listView1.Location.Y);
    }
    void ResizeForm()
    {
        //Resize form to accomodate changes.
        this.Width = listView1.Location.X + listView1.Width + 20;
    }
```

After it's all said and done, this is what it looks like:
[image]

And with 20 tabs, because why not.
[image]

Comment: `using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())` => `using (var g = tabControl1.CreateGraphics())` (better use the Graphics of the Control you're actually *measuring*) -- As described in comments, with an auto-sizing TableLayoutPanel, you just need to set `Form.AutoSize = true` (plus `GrowAndShrink`). No other calculations are needed (it's better because of DPI resizing in different screens, otherwise you'd have to consider that, too).

Comment: BTW, you should use `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` with `TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding`. Then you just need to add `1` to the calculated `Width` of each piece of text, (to include the 1px border).

Comment: Thanks much Mikael. Your code works, but the height of the tabControl1 takes up all the height of the form. How can this be changed to only use the length of the tab control?

Comment: Also, after Tab 8 in your sample there is some padding to the end. How can this be removed?